# How do you write "Miranda" in Japanese?

Tags: katakana, orthography, names

I'm sure many people learning a language have written their name in that language. Before actively learning Japanese, I noticed that any translation website changed the spelling of my name. It went from Miranda to Mirinda. Since there is a character for Ra why is it not used? Is it a matter of pronunciation?

Comment: Could you explain what do you mean by "changed the spelling"? What did you input, what did you expect to get, and what did you actually get?

Comment: More importantly, what specifically does "any translation website" refer to?

Answer (score 4):

Miranda transliterates unambiguously to ミランダ *Miranda*. In fact, ラ *ra* is pronounced [[ɺa]], where [[ɺ]] is a sound between R and L.

In fact, the names of many other people (or places) called Miranda are transcribed in this way (see [ミランダ](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%9F%E3%83%A9%E3%83%B3%E3%83%80) on Japanese Wikipedia).

You can also check the ENAMDICT database for Japanese names (via http://jisho.org, for example). The database contains a fair number of foreign names (of people and places) transliterated to Japanese. For "Miranda" they are all transliterated as ミランダ: http://jisho.org/search/miranda.

Answer (score 0):

It could be a spell checker causing the problem...

Miranda
ミ: Mi
ラ: Ra
ン: N
ダ: Da